# Displaying a localised version of iPhone Contact Picker (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization

In my app I use the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to present an address book to the user so they can select a contact from their contacts.

I want my app to support multiple localizations (English, French) and I was expecting the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to display the correct localised strings when I changed the phone's locale. However, this does not happen - no matter what language I change the iPhone to, the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController always displays English strings. This is strange as the Contacts application on the iPhone does change its text depending on the locale.

Does anyone know how to instruct the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to display the correct text for the current locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app already localized or are you just planning to add localization later? AFAIK, the built-in controls only display localized texts in those languages that your app supports.

Comment: Ah... My app is not yet localised. So to add other language support for the contact picker I need to simply add the standard en.lproj & fr.lproj?

Comment: Please try it out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

fileName : InfoPlist.strings

> > view -> Utilities -> show file inspector
> >       -> Localization "+" button click >> add language